# Remove duplicate of collection in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, collections

I have this type in my package:

```
TYPE LIST_A_TYPE TABLE OF TABLE_A%ROWTYPE;
```

Then I have this procedure where I populate this collection looping a table:

```
procedure load_me
as

  l_list_a LIST_A_TYPE
  l_rec_a  TABLE_A%ROWTYPE;

begin

  -- init collection
  l_list_a := LIST_A_TYPE ();

  for rec in (select * from table_b)
  loop

    -- do stuff that returns a TABLE_A rowtype
    l_rec_a := populate_a(rec)

    l_list_a.extend();
    l_list_a(l_list_a.count) := l_rec_a ;

  end loop;

end load_me:
```

After this loop, I have my collection full of `l_list_a`.

I need a procedure **to remove duplicates of this list** based on some columns of its definition (table).

I thought to use the SET function but keeps giving me an error.

The table TABLE_A has 30 columns. I got a 'key' of 5 columns to determine if the record could be duplicated or not...

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Let's say you have two duplicate records `[1,2, 'A', 'xyz']` and `[1,2, 'B', 'abc']` ([1,2] is your key). Which one do you like to keep or remove?

Comment: One random doesn't matter

Comment: Can you exclude the duplicates as part of the cursor query, so they are never in the collection in the first place? Or is 'do stuff' doing too much manipulation?

Comment: *"I thought to use the SET function but keeps giving me error"*. So - how did you try to use SET and what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you have to create a `MAP MEMBER FUNCTION` for the record. I don't think it can be based on `TABLE_A%ROWTYPE`, you have to define the type manually.

See this example. Object `STATIC_ROUTE` has 6 attributes and `IP_ADDRESS,NETWORK_MASK,NEXT_HOP` is the key.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STATIC_ROUTE AS OBJECT (
    ROUTE_INDEX NUMBER,
    IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(15),
    NETWORK_MASK VARCHAR2(15),
    NEXT_HOP VARCHAR2(15),
    REDISTRIBUTE VARCHAR2(5),
    ROUTE_METRIC NUMBER,
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION getId RETURN VARCHAR2)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY STATIC_ROUTE IS 

MAP MEMBER FUNCTION getId RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
    RETURN SELF.IP_ADDRESS||'-'||SELF.NETWORK_MASK||'-'||SELF.NEXT_HOP;
END;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STATIC_ROUTES  AS TABLE OF STATIC_ROUTE
/
```

Now you can use `SET` function on STATIC_ROUTES variables.

However, you should try to get the result in a single SLQ statement. It could be similar to this one:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        id_col_1, id_col_2, id_col_3, id_col_4, id_col_5, 
        FIRST_VALUE(col_6) OVER (PARTITION BY id_col_1, id_col_2, id_col_3, id_col_4, id_col_5 ORDER BY ROWID) col_6,
        FIRST_VALUE(col_7) OVER (PARTITION BY id_col_1, id_col_2, id_col_3, id_col_4, id_col_5 ORDER BY ROWID) col_7,
        FIRST_VALUE(col_8) OVER (PARTITION BY id_col_1, id_col_2, id_col_3, id_col_4, id_col_5 ORDER BY ROWID) col_8,
        ...
        FIRST_VALUE(col_30) OVER (PARTITION BY id_col_1, id_col_2, id_col_3, id_col_4, id_col_5 ORDER BY ROWID) col_30
    FROM TABLE_A)
SELECT LIST_A_TYPE(id_col_1, id_col_2, id_col_3, id_col_4, id_col_5, id_col_6, ... col_30)
BULK COLLECT INTO l_list_a
FROM t;
```